# Determining how particular SwiftKey suggestions are generated

Tags: swiftkey

Is there a way to determine how a particular SwiftKey suggestion got added to SwiftKey's dictionary of words? I'm seeing some weird suggestions pop up, and I'm pretty sure they're not words I've ever used in email or SMS.

Specifically, I wrote "Saturday," and then just started picking the strangest-looking suggestions I saw, and ended up with the following:

> Saturday, Konigsburg 45Ira Sleeps Over 157Nature's Children #Mike's Mystry 145BxcrChldrn #9Mntn Top 63Paddington

It's conceivable that I used the word "Konigsburg" at some point, and of course I've used "sleeps," "over," and "children," but I'm pretty sure I never misspelled "mystery" like that, and the others are just bizarre. I also find it strange that all of them are capitalized. Any ideas?

EDIT: To clarify, I'm not asking why these words popped up *at this particular time*; i.e., I don't want details regarding how SwiftKey selects the "best" words to display at any given time. I just want to know how these words got added as dictionary candidates at all.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to this question is very implementation specific, and can in fact only be answered for sure by a SwiftKey developer, eventually. In general, word suggestions are based on algorithms that are fed by n-gram dictionaries that predict possibilities for the next word you're likely to type.

See [Wikipedia's n-gram entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) to get more insight.

2-gram or 3-gram dictionaries are likely to be used with SwiftKey, amongst other techniques.

Regarding the strange sentence you *auto-typed* in: This reflects common use of probable 2/3-grams, so blame your fellow users on the poor spelling, it's just what they actually use.

Comment: This is probably part of the "secret sauce". I doubt Swiftkey will be forthcoming with this information.

Comment: SwiftKey also has a 'Trending Words' it looks up every hour or so. You will get some very weird stuff appearing if you have this option enabled.

Comment: Now *that* is some useful information, RossC. How do you enable/disable that option?

Comment: ce4: I'm not asking how the n-gram dictionaries work; I'm asking how these particular strings got added to the dictionaries in the first place.